# How to apply second element when using find func?

Tags: python, excel

```
import xlsxwriter
from functools import partial
def x_in_y(word, inner):
    return inner in word
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('result.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
sentence=['yns, we have to clase windows explorer, and yns, we do not need to clase the case.']
words = [('yns','yes'),('clase','close')]
row = 0
red = workbook.add_format({'font_color': 'red'})
black = workbook.add_format({'font_color': 'black'})
for wrong, correct in words:
    filtered_names = filter(partial(x_in_y, inner=wrong), sentence)
    next_elem = next(filtered_names, None)
    if next_elem:
        while next_elem:
            if len(next_elem) == len(wrong):
                worksheet.write(row, 0, next_elem, red)
            else:
                slices = []
                startIndex = 0
                index = next_elem.find(wrong)
                print(index)
                while index != -1:
                    if next_elem[startIndex: index]:
                        slices.append(black)
                        slices.append(next_elem[startIndex: index])
                    slices.append(red)
                    slices.append(next_elem[index: index + len(wrong)])
                    startIndex = index + len(wrong)
                    index = next_elem.find(wrong, startIndex)
                if next_elem[startIndex:]:
                    slices.append(black)
                    slices.append(next_elem[startIndex:])

                worksheet.write_rich_string(row, 0, *slices)
            row += 1
            next_elem = next(filtered_names, None)
workbook.close()
```

My code is to find typos in sentences and create an excel file to show the result.
However, if there are more than one typo, my results would be split into several sentences based on how many typos identified in the individual sentence.

I expect I could find all typos in the same sentence.

I guess my **next_elem.find** got a problem that it can't apply the second element in **wrong**. That makes the code write data into excel twice.

Please kindly suggest me how to revise the code.

My current result:

[image]

My expectation:

[image]

Comment: It seems like you need to flip the order of the loops. Take one sentence. Then iterate over all `words` pairs, and find all the typos while changing them to red. Only after you are done looping over `words` for a single sentence, would you append the output to the spreadsheet

Comment: Hi. I thought i did iterate all words pairs, didn't i?  Do you mean the real problem is my code doesn't loop over words for a single sentence?

Comment: IDK. Code is a bit hard to follow. Overall, I suggest using [regex `search()` or `finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-objects) which returns `Match` objects that include spans. That way you don't need to do `[startIndex:index]`. Or even use `re.sub` to just replace the sentence text directly without needing to iterate over the words of the sentence